# Performance issue Tesseract OcrApi C#

Tags: c#, performance, tesseract

I have two kinds of files (with text, without text). The first ones are fast enough whilst the second ones take forever. Is there any opportunity to speed up the process using OcrApi? I dont need it to try like forver in order to find any text.

```
var outputTxt = api.GetTextFromImage(new Bitmap(sfile));
```

Using OcrApi from tesseract lib for c#

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want to set some kind of timeout?

Comment: yes, reduce the time it spends on recognition.

Answer (score 1):

tesseract API allows you to set [timeout](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/60b07d5dd85ebd279e43452c0eedee00bb8a3cc7/include/tesseract/baseapi.h#L503) for ProcessPage function(s). Try to find out how this is implemented in your C# wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and the given recommendation. Well, I have just implemented using the timeout parameter. Unfortunately, it says 

_unexpected error_   at _Patagames.Ocr.OcrApi.ProcessPages(String filename, String retryConfig, Int32 timeout, OcrResultRenderer renderer)_

It runs smoothly with timeout = 0..